# Calling C's hello world from Python

Tags: python, c, rodeo

My C script:

```
/* Hello World program */

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello, World! \n");
   return 0;
}
```

I want to see `Hello, World!` get printed directly in my Python IDE (Rodeo IDE) in the **easiest** way possible.

So far, I've come up with the following approach, but it doesn't seem to work (and is kind of cumbersome since it requires me to go to the Terminal):

First, I do `gcc helloworld.c` in the Terminal to generate the executable `a.out*`, and then I do:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["./a.out"])
```

But instead of printing `Hello, World!` to the Python console, I just get `0` (which means success).  How can I instead make the C output print *directly* to the Python console, and how can I possibly simplify it even more (e.g., by avoiding a Terminal detour)?  I know I need to make the executable first (which is why I use Terminal) but maybe there's a sleeker way to do it within the Python IDE?

**FOR USERS WONDERING WHAT THE b STANDS FOR... @happydave's solution is tested here and thanks to @Mark Tolonen for explaining the b**

```
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> print(subprocess.check_output("./a.out"))
b'Hello, World! \n'
```

It is very strange where the `b` comes from...

Comment: C is not a scripting language. What you've displayed is your C source code. That source code must be compiled/linked to produce an executable. And then you can run the executable.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes, I know that.

Comment: Your initial reaction to happydave's answer says otherwise.

Comment: Oops, bad wording, thanks!

Comment: the `b` comes from printing the byte string output from `check_output()` directly using Python 3.x.  Python 3.x's `print` expects Unicode strings.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output("./a.out")
'Hello World!\n'
```

Regarding your second question, you could also just call gcc using subprocess.  In that case, call is probably the right thing to use, since you presumably want to check for failure before running a.out.

Here's a full script:

```
import subprocess
status = subprocess.call(["gcc","hello.c"])
if status == 0:
   print(subprocess.check_output("./a.out").decode('utf-8'))
else:
   print("Failed to compile")
```

hello.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main() {
   printf("Hello world!"); 
}
```

Output:
Hello world!

Comment: You need to compile it first.  Then, in the check_output call, just replace the arguments I showed with "a.out"

Comment: Neither `subprocess.check_output(["echo", "a.out"])` nor `subprocess.check_output(["a.out"])` works.  What am I missing?

Comment: It's quite interesting, I get `b'Hello world!'`, where is the `b` coming from?

Comment: `subprocess.check_output()` won't check for the creation of a file like `./a.out`. I don't believe you actually tried running the code in your question.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't created, only that the `subprocess.check_output("./a.out")` doesn't check for that — so is not a good way to "to check for failure before running" it.

Comment: @martineau: I agree.  I meant that warship should check the result of the call to gcc.  But I didn't include that in my example.

Comment: @happydave Please see my update, which I posted on my question above.

Comment: I see. Maybe you should [edit] your answer and make it more clear — and add the one or two line of codes to check to see if `a.out` was created.

Comment: @happydave I really don't think these latest edits are necessary, they just detract from the main topic here IMHO.

Comment: @warship: In Python 3, everything is unicode, but the shell still returns a string of bytes, which is why you see the 'b' in the string.  You can convert it using decode.  I updated my example

Comment: @happydave I would suggest you expand your answer by giving the short solution (for people like me who already know that `a.out` exists just fine) and also the solution that @martineau recommended to check for the existence of the file (which is probably useful in *real* scenarios in software engineering)

Comment: My original 2 line answer was the short solution.  I've updated it to use a.out instead of echo

Comment: happydave: True, we're cruel taskmasters, but you will be richly rewarded. `;-)`

Comment: @happydave I don't mean to be nitpicky, but `subprocess.check_output("./a.out").decode('utf-8')` returns `'Hello, World!'` not `Hello, World!`.  I don't know if this makes any difference here, but FYI.

Comment: @warship: The quotes are just the Python interpreter telling you that the result is a string.  If you print it to standard output, or write it to a file, the quotes shouldn't be there

Answer (score 4):

If you compile the C script (say, to `a.out`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   printf("Hello, World! \n");
   return 0;
}
```

You can easily call it by using [CTypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

```
# hello.py
import ctypes

beach = "./a.out"
seashell = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(beach)

seashell.main()
```

Calling the following Python script will call your `main()` in your C script:

```
$ python hello.py
Hello, World!
```

You can subprocess and capture the output using, for instance, [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects), but there's no need to spawn a shell to accomplish what you're after.

Comment: I still get `0` instead of `Hello, World!` at the moment when I run `seashell.main()`.  I'm using Python3.5 and the Rodeo IDE.

Comment: @warship There is a difference between what is printed to the standard output and the return value of the function. Have you checked both ?

Comment: @jadsq Surprisingly, this solution works perfectly for me from the Terminal, but when I try doing it in the Rodeo IDE I just get `0`.  How strange is that?!

Comment: I haven't used Rodeo IDE, but if this is the case, it's doing something incorrectly.

Comment: @warship, IDEs can wrap stdin/stdout.  You spawn a C process that is bypassing the wrapped stdin/stdout and the IDE doesn't see the output.

Comment: So what's the fix for this then (besides not using an IDE)?

Comment: @MarkTolonen LoadLibrary loads a shared lib into the Python interpreter process.  Note that if you do a trace on syscalls, you'll see no `fork()`, so unless I'm wrong, and this is always possible, this is the IDE not watching for related threads writing out. (edit: If I am wrong, please help me understand what I'm missing.)